# Electron Whisper Openai - File is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, openai-api, openai-whisper

I use whisper with the new [OpenAI V4 API](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/182) and electron. But I got an error... After some research I have found that this error is because **File interface** is only available in **browser side**, and I use this following code in the "back-end" of my electron app. But I don't find how to fix it. How I can import File inside my app ?

```
export const onWhispered = async (file: FileLike): Promise<string> => {
    try {
        const response = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
            file: file,
            model: "whisper-1"
        })
        return response.text
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error
    }    
}
```

Error:

```
App threw an error during load
ReferenceError: File is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/joris/Documents/2023 Pro/Talk To Notion/app/dist-electron/main.js:141:2307)
```